# Java GUI Windows doesn't appear at all

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in Java GUI. I was trying to create a simple login form in Netbeans. It consists of JFrame called TestSuiteFrame and a JPanel called TestSuiteEntryPanel containing a couple of labels, textboxes and a button. I have not yet added the "business logic".

The problem is that when I run the project, nothing happens. After a few seconds I get this as output: 
run:
Java Result: -1073740771
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

And that's it. No window appears. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
        package TPackage;

public class TestSuiteFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TestSuiteFrame
     */
    public TestSuiteFrame() {
        initComponents();
        TestSuiteEntryPanel a = new TestSuiteEntryPanel();
        add(a);


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //System.out.println("abc");
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestSuiteFrame b = new TestSuiteFrame();
                b.setTitle("Login");
                b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                //b.pack();
                b.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The Panel code:

```
package TPackage;
public class TestSuiteEntryPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form TestSuiteEntryPanel
 */
public TestSuiteEntryPanel() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    labelEntryName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    labelEntryPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    ButtonEntryLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
    TextEntryName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    TextEntryPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

    setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(350, 325));

    labelEntryName.setText("Name:");

    labelEntryPassword.setText("Password:");

    ButtonEntryLogin.setText("Login");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(labelEntryPassword)
                .addComponent(labelEntryName))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(TextEntryName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 221, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(TextEntryPassword))
            .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(ButtonEntryLogin)
            .addGap(45, 45, 45))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(labelEntryName)
                .addComponent(TextEntryName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(labelEntryPassword)
                .addComponent(TextEntryPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(ButtonEntryLogin)
            .addContainerGap(182, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton ButtonEntryLogin;
private javax.swing.JTextField TextEntryName;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField TextEntryPassword;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelEntryName;
private javax.swing.JLabel labelEntryPassword;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"login form ... It consists of JFrame.."*  It should probably show the login panel in a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` with the application frame visible behind it and specified as the parent component (of the dialog or option pane).  On other matters:  See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.  An [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30966147/edit) would be in order.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove whole `initComponents` method from `TestSuiteFrame` class (you don't even need it) and uncomment `pack` within `main` method. It was a problem with `GroupLayout`. 
Your code should look like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestSuiteFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TestSuiteFrame() {
        TestSuiteEntryPanel a = new TestSuiteEntryPanel();
        add(a);

    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestSuiteFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestSuiteFrame b = new TestSuiteFrame();
                b.setTitle("Login");
                b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                b.pack();
                b.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Also, keep in mind that `pack` comes after you add components on `JFrame`. Learn how to write Java Swing code by hand and avoid use of that horrible Matisse GUI builder.

Comment: I did that.(Removed initComponents() and uncommented pack()) Still the same result.

Comment: Copied and pasted the exact code as you suggested. Still get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke pack(); after all components are added to the frame.
So uncommend the pack(); call above setVilisble(true); and remove the one in the constructor :- ) 
I Hope that helped.

Comment: I did what you and Branislav suggested, but unfortunately I still get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the necessary packages (even though you probably already imported)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

Run your program. If nothing shows up and if you are using Windows, Press `alt` - `tab` to cycle through your opened applications.

**Alternatively**, after executing your program. Press `ctrl` + `alt` + `del` and check under the `Applications` tab of Windows Task Manager and see whether there exist a task by the name of `Login` (your java app).

I tried your codes, it **does shows up** a window. That JFrame from your program might be hidden by your other applications.

If you are using IDE like Netbeans, make sure the `main program file` is pointing to the `main()` within `TestSuiteFrame`.

If still nothing shows up, try running individual file instead of the entire project. `shift` + `F5` or right-click TestSuiteFrame.java => `run file` for Netbeans.

---

On top of everything, make sure you are running the correct file. You can simply write some `System.out.println()` statements within you `main()`. Just check whether the console print those line when you run your program. There are many ways to check.

If the console doesn't print those println statements, then BINGO! You are probably not running the correct java file/project.

Comment: I ran a println command and it ran correctly. However, I think the problem is with my netbeans. I ran another simpler code with just one button and it didn't work. I downloaded Eclipse and ran the same code and it worked.

Comment: @MadClownZZ Good, at least you solved your problem and you know the problem does not lies with your code.